# State space models/Kalman filter instability

Tags: r, filter, kalman-filter, ssm

I am using KFAS (in R) to estimate a local level state space model (smoothing, Gaussians). 
In order to evaluate the sensitivity of the estimation, I am introducing a single local perturbation (e.g. a small block of 20 time points with a value of zero out of 1000 time points of the signal) to each of the control signals. 
Although the small perturbations are detected in all cases, an additional fluctuations in the resulted estimates are observed throughout the signal.

Is there a way to adjust the estimation to decrease the effect of the local perturbation on the smoothing of the whole signal?

Answer (score 0):

A Kalman filter is inherently a linear filter.  So it will always multiply your erroneous signal by some gain (determined by your covariances) and add it to your state.  It is by far better to just skip filter updates when you have outliers in your measurement data.